# How to know which observable the next value comes from?

Tags: c#, system.reactive

Let's say I have something like this:

```
var observable = observable1
                 .Merge(observable2)
                 .Merge(observable3);

var subscription = observable.Subscribe(ValueHandler);

...

public void ValueHandler(string nextValue)
{
  Console.WriteLine($"Next value {nextValue} produced by /* sourceObservable */");
}
```

Short of adding that reference along with the value inside of each observable implementation, is there a way to get the source observable out of `observable1`, `observable2` and `observable3` that produced the next value?

Comment: I also don't understand why you're answering your own question so rapidly. This is a Q&A site, not a blog.

Comment: No, not rapidly. I am genuinely trying things out, and as I have questions, I post them, and while I do post them, I am at the same time still thinking about how I can solve my problem. It just so happens that I try to assimilate my thoughts and if I think I have the answer, I post it. I am not sure if my answer is right and I would just love to be educated. That's all. I am really not posting with any agenda other than to learn.

Comment: @Shlomo, http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer

Comment: I stand corrected.

Comment: @Shlomo No big whoop. :-)

Answer (score 2):

No, that's exactly the opposite of what `Merge` is designed to do. `Merge` is designed to take multiple streams and treat them like one. If you wanted some way to treat them separately, use a different operator.

---

### EDIT

As for an operator which passes on the source, the short answer is no. Rx is about reacting to messages, the source is irrelevant. I'm not even sure if you could define conceptually what a 'source' is in Rx:

```
var observable1 = Observable.Interval(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1)).Take(5);
var observable2 = observable1.Select(a => a.ToString());
var subscription = observable2.Subscribe(s => s.Dump());
```

Is the subscription source `observable1`, `observable2`, or some sort of pointer to the system clock?

If you wanted to separate the messages entering into a merge then you could use `Select` as follows:

```
var observable = observable1.Select(o => Tuple.Create("observable1", o))
  .Merge(observable2.Select(o => Tuple.Create("observable2", o)))
  .Merge(observable3.Select(o => Tuple.Create("observable3", o)));
```

If that's too messy, then you could easy make an extension method to clean it up.

---

I'll also add that the code you posted in your answer isn't very Rx-like. General guidelines are to avoid directly implementing `IObservable`. A `School` can more concisely be re-written as follows:

```
    public class School
    {
        //private Subject<Student> _subject = null;
        private readonly ISubject<Student> _applicationStream = null;

        public static readonly int MaximumNumberOfSeats = 100;

        public string Name { get; set; }

        public School(string name)
            : this(name, new Subject<Student>())
        {
        }

        public School(string name, ISubject<Student> applicationStream )
        {
            Name = name;
            _applicationStream = applicationStream;
        }

        public void AdmitStudent(Student s)
        {
            _applicationStream.OnNext(s);
        }

        public IObservable<Student> ApplicationStream()
        {
            return _applicationStream;
        }

        public IObservable<Student> AcceptedStream()
        {
            return _applicationStream
                .SelectMany(s => s != null ? Observable.Return(s) : Observable.Throw<Student>(new ArgumentNullException("student")))
                .Distinct()
                .Take(MaximumNumberOfSeats);
        }
    }
```

This way you can subscribe to all applications, the acceptances, and if you wanted to, the rejects, etc.. You also have less state (no `List<Student>`), and ideally you would even remove the `Subject<Student> applicationStream` and turn that into an Observable that gets passed in somewhere.

Comment: I think the problem is not the specific operator but that none of the operators expose any public members which provide any additional information about the context within which a value is being generated. For e.g. if I had used `Concat` instead of `Merge`, the problem would have remained.

Comment: I would like to be corrected, though. Is there an operator that combines two or more sources and that will tell you which one generated the value?

Comment: Exactly. You're right. Rx doesn't concern itself with the implementation for its interfaces. So, that's what I said. What you're doing with the `Tuple` snippet is changing the `TSource` of `IObservable<TSource>`.

Comment: Thank you very much for taking the time. Your code makes much more sense and is a lot more cleaner than mine. I actually wrote many versions of the code I listed in my answer, one of which was *close* to what you have with the two differences: I did not receive the `ISubject<T>` from the outside as a dependency, and I did not expose multiple properties such as `Accepted` and so on that represent queries over the observable. I just exposed the students as an observable.

Comment: But about having state (the `List<T>`) inside the school class is a moot point. I totally get your point and sometimes I too tend towards making things stateless as possible. And pure observables do not need to have state. But in a real world scenario, the School class would have some side-effect (store the newly admitted to a database by calling in some library) if not state. I wouldn't make it purely stateless. But I have to confess, I find a stateless world of objects more beautiful and elegant.

Comment: Side-effects, like writing to a db, work best in a subscription. Best of luck.

Comment: Do you mean side effects must be performed by the subscriber / observer inside the `onNext` handler and the observable must not be concerned with anything that dirties it (state, side-effects) and just act like a hose that signals events?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what an observable ideally is, a stream of events/messages. Any state that affects it should be either be buried/enclosed inside the observable, or explicitly exposed as a separate observable. Side-effects should ideally be in subscribers.

Comment: Most of your recent questions about Rx have included classes, which aren't the best way to learn Rx, in my opinion. Similar to how classes and re-implementing `IEnumerable` aren't helpful in learning LINQ, the same applies with learning Rx. Use Linqpad, or whatever scripting environment works for you, don't bother with OO initially.

Comment: I agree with you and understand that we mustn't normally have to implement `IObservable<T>`. My examples are not production code but simply mental exercises that are the result of thoughts like *"What if I had to..."* that occur in my mind. I am doing these purely for pleasure. I understand most operators and using them from the "outside", i.e. from the client code is fun and the easy part. I wanted to see what if I had to, knowing I shouldn't, but just, what if I just had to, just for the learning part.

Comment: I have a whole bunch of versions of these classes. I am just doing some mental gymnastics. That's all. :-)

Answer (score 0):

No, there is nothing out-of-the-box that will supply us with this information about which observable generated the value.

That is because that is an implementation detail.

If the designers of Rx had to provide this additional information, they could only do it by imposing some kind of a restriction on the `TSource` generic type parameter. And that would not be nice. That is the only way a value handler could get to know who generated the value.

So, the onus of getting this information is upon the implementation of the developer using Rx.

To make an example out of it, let us say you had a `School` class, which was an observable of students like so:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Reactive.Subjects;


namespace SchoolManagementSystem
{
    public class Student
    {
        public Student(string name)
        {
            Name = name;
        }

        public string Name { get; set; }
    }

    public class School : IObservable<Student>
    {
        private List<Student> _students;
        private Subject<Student> _subject = null;

        public static readonly int MaximumNumberOfSeats = 100;

        public string Name { get; set; }

        public School(string name)
        {
            Name = name;
            _students = new List<Student>();
            _subject = new Subject<Student>();
        }

        public void AdmitStudent(Student student)
        {
            if (student == null)
            {
                var ex = new ArgumentNullException("student");
                _subject.OnError(ex);
                throw ex;
            }

            try
            {
                if (_students.Count == MaximumNumberOfSeats)
                {
                    _subject.OnCompleted();

                    return;
                }

                if (!_students.Contains(student))
                {    
                    _students.Add(student);

                    _subject.OnNext(student);
                }
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                _subject.OnError(ex);
            }
        }

        public IDisposable Subscribe(IObserver<Student> observer)
        {
            return _subject.Subscribe(observer);
        }
    }
}
```

And the client code like so:

```
using SchoolManagementSystem;
using System;
using System.Reactive.Linq;

namespace Client
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var school1 = new School("School 1");
            var school2 = new School("School 2");
            var school3 = new School("School 3");

            var observable = school1
                .Merge(school2)
                .Merge(school3);

            var subscription = observable
                .Subscribe(PrintStudentAdmittedMessage, PrintNoMoreStudentsCanBeAdmittedMessage);

            school1.FillWithStudents(100);
            school2.FillWithStudents(102);
            school3.FillWithStudents(101);

            Console.WriteLine("Press any key to stop observing and to exit the program.");
            Console.ReadKey();
            subscription.Dispose();
        }

        static void PrintStudentAdmittedMessage(Student student)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Student admitted: {student}");
        }

        static void PrintNoMoreStudentsCanBeAdmittedMessage()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("No more students can be admitted.");
        }
    }
}
```

Then, for the client to know which school a student was admitted to, you must change the type of `TSource` of the `IObservable<TSource>`. In this case, you must change the fact that a `School` is an `IObservable<Student>`.

However, changing that goes against the semantics of the domain model. Therefore, the way to get around that would be to include a reference to the `School` inside of the student like so:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace SchoolManagementSystem
{
    public class Student
    {
        public Student(string name)
        {
            Name = name;
        }

        // Add this new property so you get this information
        // in the value handler
        public School School { get; set; }

        public string Name { get; set; }

        public override string ToString()
        {
            return string.Format($"({School.Name}: {Name})");
        }
    }
}
```

And then you would change the `AdmitStudent` method of the `School` class to indicate which school the student is being admitted to, like so:

```
public void AdmitStudent(Student student)
{
    try
    {
        if (_students.Count == MaximumNumberOfSeats)
        {
            ...
        }

        if (!_students.Contains(student))
        {
            // Add this line to indicate which school
            // the student is being admitted to
            student.School = this;

            _students.Add(student);

            _subject.OnNext(student);
        }
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        _subject.OnError(ex);
    }
}
```