# How to get the count of items in an observable stream without maintaining state yourself?

Tags: c#, system.reactive

How do I get the number of students in this school at any given point in time using the Rx idiom and without having to maintain state in the `School` class myself?

```
using System;
using System.Reactive.Subjects;

namespace SchoolManagementSystem
{
    public class School
    {
        private ISubject<Student> _subject = null;
        private int _maxNumberOfSeats;
        private int _numberOfStudentsAdmitted;

        public string Name { get; set; }

        public School(string name, int maxNumberOfSeats)
        {
            Name = name;

            _maxNumberOfSeats = maxNumberOfSeats;

            _numberOfStudentsAdmitted = 0;

            _subject = new ReplaySubject<Student>();
        }

        public void AdmitStudent(Student student)
        {
            try
            {
                if (student == null)
                    throw new ArgumentNullException("student");

                if (_numberOfStudentsAdmitted == _maxNumberOfSeats)
                {
                    _subject.OnCompleted();
                }

                // Obviously can't do this because this will
                // create a kind of dead lock in that it will
                // wait for the _subject to complete, but I am 
                // using the same _subject to issue notifications.

                // _numberOfStudentsAdmitted = _subject.Count().Wait();


                // OR to keep track of state myself
                Interlocked.Increment(ref _numberOfStudentsAdmitted);

                _subject?.OnNext(student);
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                _subject.OnError(ex);
            }
        }

        public IObservable<Student> Students
        {
            get
            {
                return _subject;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Or is this just not in tandem with the principles of components designed using Rx?

Is this something that should be the responsibility of the client (to get the count and do all side-effects in the `onNext` handler)? And that the observables should simply act as stateless signal-sources or gates much like the hardware interrupt routines that simply signal to the CPU that something of interest has happened?

In that case, we lose the criteria for the observable to signal completion. How then it is supposed to know when to complete?

Comment: You do seem to like mixing Rx with non-Rx code and asking if the code is not Rx-ish. It's because of your non-Rx code. What you're doing sounds like you need a source observable of `Student` and then do a `.Take(maxNumberOfSeats)` to populate a list. it's more like a single line of code rather than a `School` class. Can you describe more about what you're trying to do at a higher-level?

Comment: Thank you, @Enigmativity. My question(s) are not production code but just purely mental exercises. I know we shouldn't have to need to implement `IObservable<T>` and I find using the operators from the *outside* easy and fun. I am doing these exercises, as in this case, just to answer a question that arose in mind, *What if I had to have a school class with an observable of students but the school had the responsibility of not admitting any students beyond the maximum number of seats and I wanted to use a `Subject<T>` as a backing field, how would I implement it?* contd...

Comment: That's basically one part of my question. After implementing it this way, I realized that I would have to maintain state, So another question arose in my mind. Assuming that I wanted to follow along this path, would this be the only way to do it? Or would there be another way to do it without having the `School` class to maintain state? In other words three questions: (1) Is it possible to create a stateless `School` class that meets its responsibilities defined earlier? (2) Would maintaining state be the only way? (3) If there isn't another way, does this way go against the philosophy of Rx?

Comment: Please correct me if I am wrong but I understand that you're saying, "You don't need the `School` class, just use the `Take` operator from *the outside*. If that's what you're saying, I do understand and have several versions of these implementations. I was just trying to see if the requirement for disallowing admission beyond the threshold were to be in the `School` class and not on the client, would there be an Rx-way to do it? Or would you just *have* to maintain state? If you did maintain state and do what I have above, would that be a good or bad design? These are the thoughts in my mind.

Comment: I have already answered this here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38479541/how-to-know-which-observable-the-next-value-comes-from/38482489#38482489

Answer (score -3):

You can use the [Count()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh229470(v=vs.103).aspx) method on your `_subject` sequence. It will itself create an observable sequence where each value produced represents the latest total number of students in `_subject`.

You could then react to this sequence of student count values. The [Zip()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh211957(v=vs.103).aspx) operation could be useful in that regard, since it has the advantage on completing the resulting sequence when any of its inner sequences complete, which you can force with a [TakeWhile](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh244231(v=vs.103).aspx).

The result looks something like this

```
Observable.Zip(
    _subject.Select(student => != null ? student ? throw new ArgumentNullException("student")), 
    _subject.Count().TakeWhile(studentCount => studentCount < _maxNumberOfSeats),
    (student, count) => student 
);
```

All that would be left to do in the `AdmitStudent` method body would simply be to push any new student to the sequence with `_subject?.OnNext(student)` (like you already do), but without the extra logic. You could also modify this a bit to make sure that `_subject` itself also gets completed once the maximum student count is reached, but I'm not certain about your business rules, so I'll leave that for you to decide.

One last thing I can recommend if to play with the extensions for Rx types and to have a look around this website, which uses them liberally.

Comment: `Count` is an aggregation, you will only get a *single* value *after* `_subject` completes. I don't think this will work. Isn't `_subject.Take(_maxNumberOfSeats)` all that's required here?